# pandas data frame removing the first row of every numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, basically I have a data frame that has the first column looks like this:

```
#1
#2 
#2
#3
#3
#3
#3
#4
#4
#5
```

As you can see, first column is consisting of randomly repeated numbers.

First, I have to remove all the '#' then I have to remove the first row of each numbers. Since, #1 has only one row, it should go away, and only the second row of #2 remains,,, so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), last remove `#` by position with `str[1:]` or by [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
print (df)
    a
0  #1
1  #2
2  #2
3  #3
4  #3
5  #3
6  #3
7  #4
8  #4
9  #5
```

---

```
df = df.loc[df['a'].duplicated(), 'a'].str[1:]
print (df)
2    2
4    3
5    3
6    3
8    4
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Or:

```
df = df.loc[df['a'].duplicated(), 'a'].str.strip('#')
print (df)
2    2
4    3
5    3
6    3
8    4
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Detail:

```
print (df['a'].duplicated())
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8     True
9    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

EDIT:

```
df = df[df['a'].duplicated()]
df['a'] = df['a'].str.strip('#')
```

Comment: This is an interesting answer, didn't think of using `duplicated`. +1

Comment: but what if there are more than one columns and I want to return the remaining rows with all the columns after removing the first rows of each number just as you answered

Comment: @jezrael , what do you prefer, using df.loc or df["a"] .

Comment: @pyd - I prefer `df['a']` because more general as `df.a`.

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume you have a dataframe with two columns named `df`

**Setup**

```
col1 = """#1
#2
#2
#3
#3
#3
#3
#4
#4
#5""".splitlines()

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(col1=col1, col2=3.14))

df

  col1  col2
0   #1  3.14
1   #2  3.14
2   #2  3.14
3   #3  3.14
4   #3  3.14
5   #3  3.14
6   #3  3.14
7   #4  3.14
8   #4  3.14
9   #5  3.14
```

---

**Solution**
We can use Numpy's `unique` function with the `return_index` set to `True`.  What that does is return the position of the first instance of each unique value.  We then use that to identify index values and drop them.

```
_, i = np.unique(df.col1.values, return_index=True)
df.drop(df.index[i]).assign(col1=lambda d: d.col1.str[1:])

  col1  col2
2    2  3.14
4    3  3.14
5    3  3.14
6    3  3.14
8    4  3.14
```

Comment: how to use apply method instead of assign in this solution