# Detect the first change in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I facing the issue that I have an Pandas dataframe that saves the status of a variable V1 every day. I am only interested in the information when does the variable changes its status and what is the new status.

```
test_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
test_dataframe['V1'] = ['X','Y','X','X','Y','X','Y','X']
test_dataframe['Status'] = ['A','C','B','B','D','B','D','A']
test_dataframe['Date'] = [pd.to_datetime('2017-1-1'),pd.to_datetime('2017-1-2'),pd.to_datetime('2017-1-3'),pd.to_datetime('2017-1-4'),pd.to_datetime('2017-1-5'),pd.to_datetime('2017-1-6'),pd.to_datetime('2017-1-7'),pd.to_datetime('2017-1-8')]
print(test_dataframe)
```

Leading to following dataframe

```
  V1 Status       Date
0  X      A 2017-01-01
1  Y      C 2017-01-02
2  X      B 2017-01-03
3  X      B 2017-01-04
4  Y      D 2017-01-05
5  X      B 2017-01-06
6  Y      D 2017-01-07
7  X      A 2017-01-08
```

I am interested in: When does the variable change its status, and what is the new status?

The result should be:

```
V1 Status Date
-----------------
X  A      date_1
X  B      date_3
X  A      date_8
Y  C      date_2
Y  D      date_5
```

Can someone help?
THX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with `groupby` + `apply` -

```
df = df.groupby('V1', group_keys=False)\
       .apply(lambda x: x[x.Status.ne(x.Status.shift())])\
       .reset_index(drop=True)

df

  V1 Status       Date
0  X      A 2017-01-01
1  X      B 2017-01-03
2  X      A 2017-01-08
3  Y      C 2017-01-02
4  Y      D 2017-01-05
```

The `x.Status.ne(x.Status.shift())` bit will find rows where there is a change in `Status`.

Answer (score 1):

You can factorize your `Status` column and check if `diff` is not zero.

```
f = lambda s: pd.Series(s.factorize()[0], s.index)
mask = f(test_dataframe.Status).groupby(test_dataframe.V1).diff().ne(0)
test_dataframe[mask]

  V1 Status       Date
0  X      A 2017-01-01
1  Y      C 2017-01-02
2  X      B 2017-01-03
4  Y      D 2017-01-05
7  X      A 2017-01-08
```

Comment: Welcome back :-)

Comment: I'll try to answer a couple (-:

Comment: It's late, and things are slow this time of day. Don't push yourself!

Comment: I'll find ways to make it interesting https://stackoverflow.com/a/47808929/2336654